# Subsetting a data frame based on a factor level that contains a particular variable in at least one row

Tags: r, dataframe

I am quite new to R and I always try looking up a solution first before asking (so far I never had to ask, because a solution was already provided somewhere on the internet). That being said, I have trouble even coming up with a search query for my problem.

I have individual pageview data from several websites (see example below, sorry if it does not meet the usual formatting criteria). Example of a missing url in 3rd row. The dataframe is called a and is loaded through read.csv:

```
a<-read.csv("201311.csv",sep=",",colnames=c("Timestamp","user_id","url")
```

which results in:

```
 Timestamp     user_id                       url
2013-11-01  176b24938a  domain1.xy/z/66546,66546
2013-11-01  6785504947  domain2.xy/z/66346,66346
2013-10-31  0717e6b5dc
```

I have all the data lumped together in a file with 55M rows. I need to split this file in individual file for each website. Trouble is, not every pageview has a recorded URL (technical issues), in fact over 20 % of the pageviews miss a URL. Hypothetically there should be little to no overlap between the users of the sites.

I am able to subset the observations with recorded urls through the grepl() function quite easily through:

```
b <- subset(a,grepl("domain1\\.xy",a$url))
```

Now my first notion would be to assign the pageviews to individual sites through user_ids 
in case the user_id has at least one pageview with a recorded URL. Trouble is, I have no idea where to begin in R.

The example of an ideal outcome would be as follows (for domain1):

```
Timestamp       user_id                       url
2013-11-01   176b24938a  domain1.xy/z/66546,66546
2013-11-05   6785504949  domain1.xy/z/66346,66346
2013-10-31   0717e6b5dc
```

Thanks for any help and I apologize if this post doesn't follow the usual format.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should first filter your data to remove rows with missing values. Since you don't give a reproducible data it is hard to know if you have real missing values (NA) or just empty url characters.

   ```
   dat <- dat[!(is.na(dat$url) | nchar(dat$url)==0),]
   ```
2. Then you can process by url. You have many options, for example using `by`:

   ```
   by(dat,dat$url,function(x){
             fileName <- sprintf("file%s.pdf", unique(x$url)
             write.csv(x,fileName)
    })
   ```

Comment: Editted my original post a bit hope its clearer now. I am trying to divide the pageviews into separate dataframes for each website. I do this through a subset() with a grepl() function. My goal was to see how many pages users of a website access during the analysed time period in total. Observations with missing URLs make up for a substantial part of the data. The original plan was to use other pageviews for the same user in order to assign all pageviews of that user into the respective website dataframes. I can not provide any code as I have no idea which R command would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not give an example dataset with the requested output, I will have to guess:

```
# generate some data
data <- "Timestamp;user_id;url
2013-11-01;176b24938a;domain1.xy/z/66546,66546
2013-11-01;6785504947;domain2.xy/z/66346,66346
2013-10-31;0717e6b5dc;
2013-12-01;6785504947;"
data <- read.csv2(textConnection(data))
data$url[data$url == ""] <- NA

# select records with url
url <- data[!is.na(data$url), c("user_id", "url")]

# remove duplicate records
url <- url[!duplicated(url), ]
```

It is possible that some users have visited multiple sites. In the next few lines I removed these. This would, however, be a good time to check your assumption.

```
# remove user_id with different url's
duplicated_users <- url$user_id[duplicated(url$user_id)]
url <- url[!(url$user_id %in% duplicated_users), ]
```

Finally, we can use the url's in `url` to impute the missing url's in the original data set

```
data$url2 <- data$url
m <- match(data$user_id, url$user_id)
sel <- is.na(data$url)
data$url2[sel] <- url$url[m[sel]]
```

Step-by-step explanation of previous code block:

1. First create a copy of the `url` column. When imputing new values it is usually a good idea to store the original values.
2. Match the user id's of the `url` data.frame to those in the original data.frame. This will give a vector with indices. These can be used to index `url`.
3. Create a vector that selects the records with missing url's. We only want to impute new values for those.
4. By doing `m[sel]` we get the indices of the records in `url` that correspond to the records with missing url. When a user with missing url has not visited another site this index is `NA`. Then we use these indices to select the url's from `url`.

Comment: I already checked and cross-domain users do exist (I need to check how many there are and possibly treat them separately). I understand most of your code apart from the last part. The way I see it I add a new column that is the same as the original url, then you create a vector that contains the position of users that have a url in the original dataset. The sel vector contains the positions of pageviews with missing urls and then you use these positions to copy the urls into the new url2 column. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the right hand side of the last assertion? Thanks

Comment: @Tajpi Your explanation is correct. I have added some extra explanation, but I am not sure that really adds much to your explanation. `match` can be difficult to get used to. Just try it on some smaller datasets to see exactly what it does.